# AngularJS triggering ng-change by ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

As mentioned in w3schools [doc](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp):

> The ng-change event is only triggered if there is a actual change in the input value, and not if the change was made from a JavaScript.

So, when I initialize `ng-model` by `$scope` in my controller, ng-change does not trigger.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

> `change` in model value from controller will not fire change event on
>   DOM, its expected behaviour. In general event are placed on DOM not on value change.

`ng-change` event is an directive(declarative way) provided by angular for attaching `change` event on `input`/`select` element.

That means when you change in the `input`/`select` value then only that `ng-change` handler is going to fire

```
<input type="text" ng-change="changesHappen()" ng-model="testModel"/>
```

Comment: Nice description, but I have two select box and the value of the second one is providing by the first one's `ng-change` function. In one case, the first one is coming from server and set to it's `ng-model`. In this case, second select show noting.

Comment: @vahidnajafi could you please create a fiddle/plunkr?